# fmin and fmax are much slower than simple conditional operator

Tags: c++, glibc, std, math.h

I was working on some C++ code to process video frame, and found std::fmin and std::fmax is much slower than simply conditional operator. I've simplify my code as following (modify my code more C++ style as mentioned in comments):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void func()
{
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> ptr(new uint8_t[1280 * 720 * 3]);
    auto mem = ptr.get();

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i != 720; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j != 1280; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k != 3; ++k) {
                float tmp = i + j + k;
                // *mem++ = (tmp > 0.f ? (tmp < 255.f ? tmp : 255.f) : 0.f) + 0.5f;
                *mem++ = std::round(fmin(255.f, fmax(0.f, tmp)));
            }
        }
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "cost " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end - start).count() << "ms\n";
}

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    while (i--) func();
}
```

The output cost of this code is about 20ms on my machine (with `g++ -O3 test.cpp`):

```
cost 21.1324ms
cost 20.8892ms
cost 19.9664ms
cost 19.9693ms
cost 19.9603ms
```

And if I replace all std lib math functions with my own code (by uncomment code above), the output cost is just about 4ms:

```
cost 3.90695ms
cost 3.48335ms
cost 3.02623ms
cost 2.65635ms
cost 2.76906ms
```

I've tried std::fmin and std::fmax (and std::round too) separately, they are all much slower. For example:
`*mem++ = fmax(0.f, tmp);`

```
cost 9.31014ms
cost 8.86421ms
cost 7.8366ms
cost 7.86914ms
cost 7.82036ms
```

vs `*mem++ = tmp > 0.f ? tmp : 0.f;`

```
cost 3.50026ms
cost 3.05906ms
cost 2.33485ms
cost 2.36281ms
cost 2.38488ms
```

For std::round here, if I simply delete it, just run `*mem++ = fmin(255.f, fmax(0.f, tmp));`, the time cost improve about 7ms:

```
cost 13.4067ms
cost 13.2468ms
cost 12.1877ms
cost 12.2698ms
cost 12.1878ms
```

1. std::fmin, std::fmax, std::round are all constexprs, and I thought there should not be function invoke overhead.
2. I know std::round does more than simply +0.5f and assign to integer, but it's still much slower than my expectation.

`g++ -v` on my system (Ubuntu 20.04, x86-64):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

Comment: Any question concerning the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by the compiler and compiler optimization settings or flags used to build the application.  If you are timing a "debug" or unoptimized build, the timings you are showing are meaningless.

Comment: First remark, malloc is generally consider to be more of C function, than C++, it is often regarded as bad coding in C++ where you'd prefer the usage of the new operator. Next bad habit is that comparison operators such as > and < should be use only on integer, and comparison between float should be more something like |my_float1-my_float2| < epsilon, where epsilon is small and you fixe it. In that manner, I expect that fmin and fmax would do something more sophisticated than your commented line, hence the time delay.

Comment: You should not be executing the second call to `now` in a `printf` call.  It should be called independent of `printf`.  You are potentially adding extraneous time by the execution of the call to `printf`, the processing of the parameter list, etc.  It should be something like this: `auto stoptime = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();` -- then you print `stoptime`

Comment: I'm guessing you're not using optimisations resulting in the functions not being inlined, function calls are relatively expensive

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I compiled with simply g++ -O3 test.cpp. I initially add compiler and flag in my question and might accidentally undo  
it. Add it back again now. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: `g++ --version`? What OS?

Comment: Benchmark link with similar results: https://quick-bench.com/q/MrLDiVBMZcua3eydA0mx5-LBh9A

Comment: You might want to use the flag `-ffast-math`

Comment: @DanielLangr `-OFast` has swapped the results: https://quick-bench.com/q/YkGyCzzll8f8mwB5nYTJD-xJSaI

Comment: `std::round` has to do more sophisticated work than simply comparing against `0.5`.

Comment: Using [`std::clamp(tmp, 0.f, 255.f)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) gives you back the fast speed compared to the fmin/fmax combination.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. "Clamp and add 0.5" is not the same as "clamp and round".

Comment: If you are using C++ then instead of `uint8_t* mem = (uint8_t*)malloc(1280 * 720 * 3);` use `std::vector<std::uint8_t> mem(1280*720*3);` Manual memory managment should be avoided (and malloc should not be used at all)

Comment: With `-O3`, the functions are not inlined. With `-Ofast` or `-ffast-math`, functions are inlined, but fmin/fmax/round results in significantly more instructions. Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/EG3PPh436.

Comment: `uint8_t r = x + 0.5f` is not the same as `uint8_t r = std::round(x)` - the first one never results in 0.

Comment: "...are all constexpr and I thought there is no function invoke overhead here" `constexpr` only means that potentially it can be evaluated at compile time, but `tmp` is a runtime value

Comment: please do not remove includes and using declarations from your code. They are part of the code. Removing them does not make the code simpler to read and understand, but rather more difficult to compile

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: @ThibaultCimic I agree concerning the fact that floating point has to be compared with care in general. Though, just applying an epsilon everywhere might be wrong as well. (According to my experience, epsilons are often enough too large or too small or even both.) And sometimes, you just don't need it. E.g. if I intend to apply `asin()` or `acos()` and the arguments might be a tiny bit over 1.0 or under -1.0 (due to previous rounding issues) just checking (with `>` or `<`) and clamping appears very appropriate to me.

Comment: Btw, you are not using `std::fmin` and `std::fmax` but `fmin` and `fmax` from global names which should be C functions from [math.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmin) which is usually implicitly included when including `cmath`. Also `std::fmin` and `std::fmax` are not [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmin) until c++23

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Completly agree, my point was just to emphasis the fact that comparison of float is more complex and you should know what you're doing in your case, hence calling fmin and fmax might be slower because they do more complex stuff

Comment: About slow `std::round`, this is due to an unfortunate choice in its specification. If you can use `std::nearbyint` it's normally much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As always, with performance questions, the hardware and software stack are both important and empirical measurement is the arbiter of truth. In this particular instance, the platform makes a big difference that is not intuitive or easily predicted.

I used [nanobench](https://github.com/martinus/nanobench) to test three different options for the computation in question. Here are the results for two different platforms (one arm64, one x86).

*M1, Mac OSX 13.4, Clang-16*

| ns/op | op/s | err% | total | benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3,166,542.00 | 315.80 | 13.1% | 0.04 | `compare` |
| 1,988,667.00 | 502.85 | 7.3% | 0.02 | `round-fminmax` |
| 1,911,292.00 | 523.21 | 3.6% | 0.02 | `clamp` |

*Xeon, Ubuntu 20.04, Clang-17*

| ns/op | op/s | err% | total | benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6,763,898.00 | 147.84 | 0.5% | 0.08 | `compare` |
| 10,629,358.00 | 94.08 | 0.2% | 0.13 | `round-fminmax` |
| 5,131,994.00 | 194.86 | 0.0% | 0.06 | `clamp` |

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "nanobench.h"

using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;

template<class T>
auto clamp(const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi) {
    return v < lo ? lo : hi < v ? hi : v;
}

template<class Op>
void func(uint8_t *mem, Op&& op)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 720; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j != 1280; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k != 3; ++k) {
                float tmp = i + j + k;
                *mem++ = op(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> ptr(new uint8_t[1280 * 720 * 3]);
    auto *mem = ptr.get();

    ankerl::nanobench::Bench().run("compare", [&]() {
        func(mem, [](float x) {
            return (x > 0 ? (x < 255 ? x : 255) : 0) + 0.5;
        });
    });

    ankerl::nanobench::Bench().run("round-fminmax", [&]() {
        func(mem, [](float x) {
            return std::round(fmin(255.f, fmax(0.f, x)));
        });
    });

    ankerl::nanobench::Bench().run("clamp", [&]() {
        func(mem, [](float x) {
            return clamp(x + 0.5f, 0.0f, 255.0f);
        });
    });
}
```